# S3 Image Upload Component Failing on Privately Routed Page, but not Public one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, redux

I have created an image upload component that will upload one image to S3. The exact same component works on one page (`DevPage` in AppRouter), not another (`Dashboard` page in AppRouter).

When attempted from the Dashboard (Private) page, the error is this:

```
xhr.js:178 PUT https://<domain>.s3.amazonaws.com/dummyCo/images/5eb9927c5e23ef001719395f/48da9506-dc13-465a-b3f5-928334d33f47?AWSAccessKeyId=<redacted>&Content-Type=png&Expires=1593609319&Signature=<redacted>-amz-acl=public-read 400 (Bad Request)

image (S3) upload error Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

But when run on the DevPage, it is successful. I am completely baffled - please help!

The line responsible for uploading an image to S3.

`dispatch(uploadImage(uploadInput.files[0], dummyObsId, dummyCompany))`

And it works when it is rendered on a publicly routed page, but not on a privately routed page.

`AppRouter.js` (with some routes removed for brevity)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from 'history'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

import DashboardPage from '../views/Dashboard/DashboardPage'
import DetailPage from '../views/DevPage/DevPage';
import LoginPage from '../views/Login/LoginPage'

import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'
import PublicRoute from './PublicRoute'

import Minimal from '../layouts/Minimal/Minimal'
import Main from '../layouts/Main/Main'

import theme from '../theme';

export const history = createHistory()

const AppRouter = () => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                
                <PublicRoute
                    path="/"
                    component={DevPage}
                    layout={Main}
                    exact={true}
                />

                <PrivateRoute
                    path="/dashboard"
                    component={DashboardPage}
                    layout={Main}
                />

            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
)

export default AppRouter
```

Then, the Public Route compared with the Private Route

```
// PublicRoute
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

export const PublicRoute = (props) => {
    const { isAuthenticated, layout: Layout, component: Component, ...rest } = props

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(matchProps) => (
            isAuthenticated
                ? (
                    <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
                ) : (
                    <Layout>
                        <Component {...matchProps} />
                    </Layout>

                )
        )} />
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.token
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PublicRoute)
```

and

```
// PrivateRoute
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

export const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
    const { isAuthenticated, layout: Layout, component: Component, ...rest } = props

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(matchProps) => (
            isAuthenticated
                ? (
                    <Layout>
                        <Component {...matchProps} />
                    </Layout>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to='/' />
                )
        )} />
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.token
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute)
```

On the API, the route responsible for getting the signed request:

```
router.post('/sign_s3', (req, res) => {

    const s3 = new aws.S3();
    const fileName = req.body.fileName;
    const fileType = req.body.fileType;

    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        Key: fileName,
        Expires: 500,
        ContentType: fileType,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            res.status(400).send({ success: false, error: err })
        }

        const returnData = {
            signedRequest: data,
            url: `https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
        };

        res.status(200).send({ success: true, data: { returnData } })
    });
})
```

And finally the redux action responsible for doing the work on the UI side...

```
export const uploadImage = (file, observationId, company) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_AWS_URL_PENDING })

    const fileName = `${company}/images/${observationId}/${uuidv4()}`
    const fileType = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, file.name.length) || file.name;

    api.post('/sign_s3', { fileName, fileType })
        .then((response) => {

            if (response.status === 200) {
                dispatch({ type: REQUEST_AWS_URL_SUCCESS, payload: response.data })
                dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_PENDING })

                const signedRequest = response.data.data.returnData.signedRequest;
                const url = response.data.data.returnData.url
                
                const options = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': fileType
                    }
                }
                
                const imageData = {
                    observationId: observationId,
                    imageKey: url
                }

                api.put(signedRequest, file, options)
                    .then(response => {                        

                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS })
                            // dispatch({ type: SAVE_METADATA_PENDING })

                            api.post('/save_image', imageData)
                                .then((response) => {
                                    if (response.status === 200) {
                                        dispatch({ type: SAVE_METADATA_SUCCESS })
                                    }
                                })

                                .catch((error) => {
                                    dispatch({ type: SAVE_METADATA_FAILED, payload: error })
                                    console.log('metadata (mongoDB) upload error', error)
                                })
                        }
                    })

                    .catch((error) => {
                        dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_FAILED, payload: error })
                        console.log('image (S3) upload error', error)
                    })
            }
        })

        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({ type: REQUEST_AWS_URL_FAILED, payload: error.message })
            console.log('signed request (api - S3) error', error)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I had to use a 'naked' version of Axios to make the put request to S3.

I was previously using the instance of Axios declared in my API file....

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '../redux/store'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
})

instance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        const token = store.getState().auth.token

        if (token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
        }
        return config
    },
    (e) => {
        return Promise.reject(e)
    }
)

export default instance
```

which was messing with my headers when I was authenticated. AWS did not like this.

The solution was to change the Redux action from

```
import api from '../api'
...
 api.put(signedRequest, file, options)
...
```

to

```
import axios from 'axios'
...
 axios.put(signedRequest, file, options)
...
```

While leaving the rest of the API calls on the default API Axios instance.